# How to work with start and stop bits in serial communication (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I need to communicate with a device using Arduino through RS232, I have everything setup and working. My problem is that the company that made the device a I need to communicate with told me the following:

1) The data sent through serial have one start and stop bit and is the hex "7E".
2) On the end of the message is appended a CRC hash

The device uses a request/response protocol, so the Arduino board must send the data in order to receive something. I've set the start and stop bit as ASCII characters put the data and CRC in between and simply `Serial.write(data)`; I've setup two Arduino boards and both communicating this way. Everything went fine.

But with the device itself it's not working. The device sends back a response like "CE   0F     " with spaces in between. So I start searching more about serial communication and found about start and stop bits and parity and start wondering if I'm sending and receiving data in the way the device expects.

To send and receive I used the basics tutorials like:

```
   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            // read the incoming byte:
            incomingByte = Serial.read();

            // say what you got:
            Serial.print("I received: ");
            Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
    }
```

So far I don't understand very well this type of communication. So I want to know why, for example some resources says that the start bit is 0 and the stop bit is 1, and in this case the start and stop bit is "7E".

I'm suspecting that this has something with:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control

Comment: `"CE"` instead of 7E looks like a mis-matched data length (7 vs 8).  Bits are sent LSBit first.  (or slight baud difference)

Comment: Forget High-Level Data Link Control; that's for synchronous communication.  RS-232 is asynchronous.  The start and stop bits frame each and every character.  The UART frames each character prior to transmission, and strips them off when received.  It's all handled in the HW, and the only SW involved is configuring the number of stop bits.  From your broken English, the hex value `7E` is apparently the start character of a message, and the message is terminated with a CRC..

Comment: A serial communication must first be configured in the Serial.begin instruction i.e. select the number of stop bit, and the type of parity bit. By default it's 8N1 : 1 start bit, 8 data bits, no parity bit and 1 stop bit. You can find here the list of possible serial port configurations for Arduino : https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/begin Once it's configured the Serial.read will return the data bits (and never the start/stop/parity bits). Notice that if the serial port wasn't configured correctly, the value returned by Serial.read will likely be incorrect.